# MVC generic popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, popup

I am looking to create a generic popup which can be opened from anywhere in the application using a button. The idea is that this popup will have a tree and user will click on node and it will return selected node (or Id related to that node). to the page where this popup is been called from.

I have created the treeview popup but the problem is I am not sure how to make this popup return something to the calling page. The calling page is not going to be a view it could be any view.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using a javascript function, you can call a function on the popup's parent page using the `opener` variable.

on parent page call this:

```
opener.SelectedNode(popupSelectedNodeId);
```

Where SelectedNode is a function on all your parent pages, and popupSelectedNodeId is the node that is selected on your popup page.

Comment: Thats a good point but is there anyway to have @Ajax.ActionLink on each node and when you submit it does HttpGet (or HttpPost) to the calling controller?

Comment: It really depends on how you do your markup. If you create a reusable partial view, you can do what you're talking about, but to ensure that Html.ActionLink is generating the correct dynamic link, you will need to include the link parameters in your partial view Model